Penning trap laser cooling
In the penning trap, I know that there is a quadrupole electric field and a magnetic field.
This results in three eigen motions with three eigen frequencies: magnetron freq, modified cyclotron freq, axial freq.
Then I was reading a paper and it said that they use the quadrupole for axialization to make the doppler cooling more effective.
Then I looked at other papers about axialization, and I'm confused now.
My question is, is the axialization that was mentioned in doppler cooling different from the one that is driving the axial frequency?

As a suggestion, it might be helpful to include a reference to the paper mentioned in case someone wants to double check some details.  Thank you.

Great question!
The electrostatic potential that helps to trap the particles is of the form
$$ \Phi_\text{trap} \propto x^2 + y^2 - 2z^2 \quad .$$
The potential that helps to couple axial and radial modes (for "axialization") is of the form
$$ \Phi_\text{coupling} \propto xz \quad .$$
Both are quadrupolar fields, but they have a different spatial configuration. Also, there is a difference in the time-dependence: The trapping potential is static. The coupling potential is modulated at a frequency of $\nu_\text{rf} = v_+ - v_z $ for coupling the axial and the cyclotron mode, and at $\nu_{rf} = v_z - v_- $ for coupling the axial and the magnetron mode.
Fun fact: There are 5 independent ("orthogonal") quadrupole fields! The corresponding electric potentials are simple polynomials: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/231622/24983
